# Extracting from Response Header with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, header, jmeter, response-headers

I'm trying to extract the confirmation number at the end of the location tag in the response header to a page using RegEx.  The response header is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2013 17:55:50 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://test.regtest.com/cart/confirmation?confirmationNumber=00284031
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 0
X-Cnection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

For instance, if in the header the line is this:

```
Location: http://test.regtest.com/cart/confirmation?confirmationNumber=00284031
```

I am looking to return this to use as a variable later:

> 00284031

My current RegEx expression is something like this:

```
Location: http://test.regtest.com/cart/confirmation?confirmationNumber=(\d+)?
```

I am new to RegEx and what I wrote above is based off the example at the following link:

http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/extracting-text-from-a-page-and-using-it-somewhere-else-in-jmeter

I need this confirmation number for a dynamic page redirect for a Jmeter script I am writing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you require additional information to help answer the question let me know!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you look at my answer, if an answer solved your problem then you should accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `Location: [\S]+?confirmationNumber=(\d+)`

Your issue is the use of special characters in the string without escaping them - e.g.: `?` and `/`

**Note** my `?` is not matching the question mark in front of confirmationNumber, but instead is making the `[\S]+` non-greedy.

If you want to be explicit, your version should work if modified like this to escape the characters with special meaning:

```
Location: http:\/\/test.regtest.com\/cart\/confirmation\?confirmationNumber=(\d+)?
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and explained answer.  In the end the very verbose expression worked best as the program I am using is VERY picky.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to match the entire line to get the confirmation number, instead you can just match the number like this:

```
(?<=confirmationNumber=)(\d+)
```

`(?<=confirmationNumber=)` is called a look behind, what the expression says is to match one more digits `(\d+)` and put them into a group, only if those digits are preceded by the following string `confirmationNumber=`.

[Rege101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xR5dB2)

Comment: Thank you! This worked out great for me.  The program I was using, JMeter, is VERY picky.  You're explanation helped a lot as well.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp as following

```
confirmationNumber=([0-9]+)
```